# Was the Windows Profiling API removed as of the Windows 10 SDK?

Tags: c++, .net, profiling

Specifically, the one described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/

I can find CorProf.h under the Windows 8.1 SDK include directory but not the Windows 10 SDK include directory.

Was the API removed in Windows 10? Was the header file renamed? Was the header file moved to a different location? Was my installation of the windows 10 SDK somehow messed up? I've been unable to track down any information as to what might be going on.

I feel like there must be something obvious I'm missing.

Small update: I found a blog ( https://naughter.wordpress.com/2017/08/06/changes-in-the-windows-v10-0-16232-sdk-compared-to-windows-v10-0-15063-sdk-part-two/ ) while searching around for answers that had this to say, but I'm not entirely sure of the implications:
"cor.h, cordebug.h/idl, CorError.h, CorHdr.h, corhlpr.h, corprof.h/idl, corpub.h/idl & corsym.h/idl: All of these header files have been removed. They are all the native mode COM interface to .NET."

Comment: They were moved, getting versioned by the framework version since 4.6.  Look in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.x.y\Include\um.  Not sure whose responsible for deploying, it might be the VS installer.

Comment: @HansPassant I verified that the header is located under that path on my PC. It makes sense for it to be associated with .NET framework version rather than a Windows SDK, I just wish Microsoft had documented that it moved! I don't know why my file search didn't turn it up in the first place, but oh well. If you post this comment as an answer, I can mark this question answered since it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Even with Hans' hint, it still took me a while to figure out which package deploys the NetFxSDK, so hope below information is helpful for someone.

1. Get the Win 10 SDK from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/
2. Make sure select .NET Framework Software Development Kit
3. The library and include files will be in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK<.net version>\

[image: Installation menu for NetFxSDK]